# How to separate rails applications due to postgres database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I'm new in Ruby on Rails, and even more new in postgres. I have several applications in RoR with postgres db. I would like to separate psql databasis for every of rails app. Now it seems like every rails app would take one db, because I cannot do rake db:migrate after command AddColumn with the name of a column, which is exacly the same as in another rails app.
I suppose I would have to set something in psql? I work with Ubuntu 14.04.
If I should specify something please let me know.

Comment: Now I know it depends on database name. And there is another question: I have got cloned from github app. I'd already had few more of apps with databasis with the same db name. How can I change this new app's db name, as to not connect new db with old ones?

Comment: rake db:create:all worked for me after changing name in /config/databases.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't a good idea to manually manipulate a database after it has been created by rails unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing, you could quickly break your app. As far as seperating your apps into different databases, the database that your app will use is configured in /config/databases.yml:

```
default:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: database_name
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Keep in mine, a database can have multiple tables within it. I believe by default, rails uses a table with the same name as your model, to create less confusion, so be sure you don't have a model with the same name as another in your database.

You can look into this a little more by running:

```
user:~$ psql
user=# \list
user=# \d+
```

\list in psql will show your databases, while \d+ will show your tables.

FYI, you can exit the listing by pressing 'q'

Best of luck!

Comment: `Ctrl+D` (End-of-File) exits `psql` as well.

Comment: \q is the correct way to exit psql, I was simply saying to exit whatever psql uses to display the table lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how can I change name of the database with rails (now, after it was created and connected with rails?